# How to study the interior of such set: $\{ f \in X | \forall x \in D, f(x)=0 \} $ in $(X, ||\cdot||_{\infty})$, $X = C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

How to study the interior of such set: $\{ f \in X | \forall x \in D, f(x)=0 \} $ in $(X, ||\cdot||_{\infty})$,  $X = C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$

> So we work in $(X, ||\cdot||_{\infty})$, where $X = C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ and  $D \subset [0,1]$. I need to study the interior this set: $$A=\{ f \in X | \forall x \in D, f(x)=0 \} $$

I am not sure how to find the elements $ f$ such that there would exist $r>0$, $B(f,r) \subset A$. Any help would be welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any element $f \in A$ and assume you can find a ball $B(f,\epsilon) \subset A$. Then prove that $g$ defined by $g(x) = \frac{\epsilon}{2}; \forall x \in D$ is inside of the ball, but $g \not \in A$. So this can help you conclude that $\text{Int}(A) = \emptyset$

Answer (score 1):

I think the demonstration depends on the nature of $D$. If $D$ is an interval, the answer is easy.

The interior you are looking for is then empty : for any function $f$ of $A$, and any $\epsilon>0$, ${\rm B}(f,\epsilon)$ cannot be included in $A$. For example, consider a non nul function $\delta$, that takes value $0$ at the edges of $D$, and which is bounded by $\epsilon/2$ (visualize a "peak" function, sorry, I don't have time to draw a picture :-). Then $f+\delta\in{\rm B}(f,\epsilon)$, and $f+\delta\notin A$.

I think you can work the general case from here.

Answer (score 1):

A function $f$ that is near to another function $g$ is just such that at every $x$ we look at, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are close together. This is what $d(f,g) = \sup_{x \in x} |f(x) - g(x)|$ measures.
Your set is defined by being exactly $0$ on *all* points of $D$. But we can vary $f(x)$ a little bit (keeping it continuous, so points near to $x$ also change) to make it non-$0$ in any of those points.

$f \in A$ being in the interior of $A$ (in this metric space) means that there is some positive "wiggle room" $r>0$ around $f$ such that any variation of $f$ within distance $r$ keeps us inside $A$. But intuitively we can never do that for your zero-set on $D$. Formally if $f \in A$, and $r>0$, the function $g(x) = f(x) + \frac{r}{2}$ is just as continuous as $f$ and $d(f,g) = \frac{r}{2} < r$ but $g(x) = \frac{r}{2} \neq 0$ for any $x \in D$. So if $D \neq \emptyset$, the interior of your set is empty.